# Jquery and ScriptDB connexion

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

I am a novice developer, I'm just working with Google Apps Script, I really like and seems easy, but now I have encountered a problem, I have a database in ScriptDB, I have a suggestion box jquery my question is if I can connect with ScriptDB jquery or is there some bridge, I would be helpful your answers Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very broad, it would help if you added more detail & some code to show what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

The "bridge" is your .gs code. Takes what jquery gives you (from the browsers js in htmlservice) and pass it to a server function in .gs which has access to scriptdb.